# What is 2 choose2?

Tags: combinatorics

2 choose 2 will result in a undefined answer, if computed using the binomial coefficient. For 
$\left(\frac{2!}{2!(2-2)!}\right)^2$ has 0 in its denominator. But then why the correct answer is 1.

Comment: I just edited...

Comment: $0!=1{{{{{}}}}}$

Comment: Ok, I may now close this question

Comment: no ... just leave it as it is. I think there is a nice video on youtube explaining it.

Comment: [There you go](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mfk_L4Nx2ZI)

Answer (score 4):

$0!$ is well-defined:

$$0! = 1\neq 0$$

This invokes what we call the [*empty product*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0!#Frequent_examples).